# Replace one local branch with another local branch... and preserving tracking

Tags: git, git-branch, branching-and-merging, git-remote

I have 2 local branches that are tracking different repositories:

- local-live ( tracks our live repo )
- local-staging ( tracks a staging repo )

We have "continous deployment" set up so when I push my local-staging up staging environment will be updated with the changes.  I want staging to reflect the code that's on live( which isn't the case currenly).

How might I replace my "local-staging" branch with code from my "local-live" branch?  I want to wipe all staging changes making staging reflect what's on live.  I want my local-staging to still be tracking the staging repo( ie "git push" from staging will act as expected )

Hope this is clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you want to do a hard reset.

```
git checkout local-staging
git reset --hard local-live
```

Comment: I though the last argument in "git reset" should be a commit you want to reset to.  Does it work with branch name as well?

Comment: @RayL yup, absolutely. try it out. And accept the answer if it works..:)

Comment: Most concise answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you want to merge your live branch into your staging branch.

Here is a detailed guide to do that:

http://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/ebook/command-line/branching-merging/merging

Basically you have to do this:

```
$ git checkout local-staging
$ git merge local-live
```

---

Now, if you wanna put the changes of your live branch on top of staging branch you should use rebase.
And do something like:

```
$ git checkout local-live
$ git rebase local-staging
$ git checkout local-staging
$ git merge local-live
```

Check this:

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing

---

Now, if you don't want to merge the branches you shoud do a destructive operation :O

You can do a "hard reset" and a "force push".

```
$ git checkout local-staging
$ git reset --hard <desired commit of local-live>
$ git push --force origin local-staging
```

More info:

https://es.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/undoing-changes/git-reset

Comment: I don't want to merge at all. i want to replace what's on staging( loose any changes on staging).  Sorry, i just updated the question.  hope that makes sense.